# Python 3.4 Panda sort market-data by Date

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, pandas

I am trying to set up Python (3.4) code to sort a time-series by date.

In python shell, I key in the following

```
>>>data = quandl.get("YAHOO/INDEX_GSPC", start_date="2017-01-01", end_date="2017-01-20")
>>>print(data)
```

So, I can load in the data. But when I try to use sort by the command

```
>>>data = data.sort_values(by='Date')
```

I get the following list of errors messages. I can't seem to understand/get the syntax for date sort from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html

Experts out there......., many thanks for advice.

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2134, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4433)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13742)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'Date'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    data = data.sort_values(by='Date')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3230, in sort_values
    k = self.xs(by, axis=other_axis).values
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1770, in xs
    return self[key]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2059, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2066, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1386, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3543, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2136, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4433)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13742)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Answer (score 1):

`quandl.get` loads a `DataFrame` with the date as index.

So if you sort by index, you're good to go:

```
data = data.sort_index()
```

Comment: thanks, it works now. I use data = data.sort_index(Ascending=False) and I can get it to display the data, by date, with the most recent at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you look at the error. You are getting a `KeyError` which means that the column `Date` does not exist in your DataFrame. It's like that the dates are stored in the index which requires the `sort_index` method instead. The 'Date' name that you see in your DataFrame is the **name** of the index and not a column.

```
data.sort_index()
```